# Problem with either Write permission or Path while saving Log files in MVC5 application --

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, permissions, streamwriter, system.io.file

I'm trying to write exception log messages using StreamWriter in my MVC5 web application.

The main method --

```
public bool WriteApplicationException(string exp_message)
    {
        try
        {
            filename = string.Format("LogMessages\\{0}_{1}.log", "Exception", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

            string logFilePath = string.Format(Path.Combine(@"{0}\{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, filename));

            //logFilePath = logFilePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("----------------------------------------------------");
            sb.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(exp_message);
            sb.AppendLine("----------------------------------------------------");

            //StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true)
            using (StreamWriter swr= File.AppendText(logFilePath))
            {
                swr.Write(sb.ToString());
                swr.Flush();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am calling it on the override void OnException in my relevant controller class.
The path that's being generated is as such -
*drivelabel:\LogProject.UI\LogProject.UI\LogProject.Web\LogMessages\Exception_3/2/2020.log*

But the exception that is being thrown is as such -

```
{"Could not find a part of the path 'drivelabel:\\LogProject.UI\\LogProject.UI\\LogProject.Web\\LogMessages\\Exception_3\\2\\2020.log'."}
```

So, could there be any read/write permission issue that is preventing this? Or anything with firewall?
The 2nd one is most unlikely. What could it be? Like I said, the path is very much existent and within the project structure itself. Not outside. What issue here? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The message is not telling you that you do not have the right permissions, it is telling you that this path or a part of it  does not exist. You need to manually , (or programatically) create that path before you can write to ot.

Comment: which is strange. cuz all seems fine and the path seems to exist just fine. let me cross check in that case(pretty sure it's not needed). like I said, the path is already pre-created in my project folder structure already.    @arbemo58

Comment: I double checked the path - as was expected. Nothing wrong or missing there. Only thing else could be, escape sequence on that path string I am forming. Although I have tried a fair number of combinations on that too.